# ggplot2 keeps adding .5 at end of Year variable on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

So I am trying to make a grouped bar chart, with `Year` on the x axis and `Number` on the y, grouped by `Nationality` and faceted by `Municipality`.  Below is a look at the data (2017 is in the middle so not shown).

```
> head(pres_munic)
  Year              Municipality Nationality Number
1 2016        Tapachula, Chiapas  Salvadoran   2141
2 2016        Acayucán, Veracruz  Salvadoran   4697
3 2016 Tuxtla Gutiérrez, Chiapas  Salvadoran   2327
4 2016           Centro, Tabasco  Salvadoran   1811
> tail(pres_munic)
     Year                                   Municipality Nationality Number
1328 2018                  San Pedro Tapanatepec, Oaxaca    Honduran    365
1329 2018                             Huehuetán, Chiapas    Honduran    417
1331 2018                               Iztapalapa, CDMX    Honduran    247
1332 2018                             Saltillo, Coahulia    Honduran    352
```

For some reason, ggplot2 keeps making the x axis "2016" on one tick, then "2016.5" on the next tick, and so on to 2018.5. I don't know why it is doing this, because in my year variable I don't have a .5 after any of those years. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjkVP.jpg) is what my rough graph looks like, showing the weird axis at the bottom.

My code is as follows, sorry if it's messy.

```
ggplot(pres_munic, aes(Year, Number)) + facet_wrap(~ Municipality) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Nationality), 
                                          width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") +  
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.title = 
      element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Anyone have any idea how I can change this? Or at least make it so the axis only shows 2016, 2017, 2018? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `pres_munic$Year <- as.factor(pres_munic$Year)` before your ggplot command? If you want to have a proper solution it might be worth providing a reproducible exmaple by giving us the output of `dput(pres_munic)`.

Comment: I acctualy do not work with R, but it seems to be some of AUTO scale goingon, may you should tell to not do that?

Comment: The year is a numeric value. That's the problem...

Comment: @JonGrub thank you for that-- I just realized I should've done that since it is seeing it as a numeric variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Year` is numeric, ggplot will interpret it as continuous data that can be split up with decimal points. To prevent this, we can specify the position of tick marks with `scale_x_continuous`:

```
ggplot(pres_munic, aes(Year, Number)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Municipality) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Nationality), width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:2100) +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.title = 
      element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Comment: `0:2100` is a fixed year sequence. In case anyone needs it more dynamic based on the actual `years in their `d`ata: `min(d$y):max(d$y)` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That solution will look bad if there are many years. You might want to use ggplot's automatic date scaling.

```
pres_munic$Date <- as.Date(paste(pres_munic$Year, 1, 1, sep="-"))
ggplot(pres_munic, aes(Date, Number)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Municipality) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Nationality), width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.title = 
      element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Comment: This doesn't work unless the year variable is from an object with class <Date>.